# Edit framework class implementation Android for backward compatibility

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, reflection, android-viewpager

I am trying to use `ViewPager.PageTransformer` interface in old Android 2.2 application. My target API is 8 Level. But there is known check in `ViewPager` compat library class

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        final boolean hasTransformer = transformer != null;
        final boolean needsPopulate = hasTransformer != (mPageTransformer ....
    }
```

So because of this check `PageTransformer` doesn't work in old Androids even with great `NineOldAndroids` library.
I know there are some solutions available, one of them is to change default implementation of `ViewPager` class. Futhermore, fork of dafault compat library without this check is available on github.
Of course I can use this library or just change it by myself and use my custom `ViewPager` class.
But in this case a lot of problems appear.
Most important that you cannot use this custom class with other libraries, for instance `ViewPageIndicator`, because they have been created for default `ViewPager` class.
Firstly,what I want to implement ?

My idea is to create some library and custom view for my purposes, this custom view will include page indicator, view pager and some other views.

So user of the library don't have to work with `ViewPager` directly it will use only custom view and some other classes from the library.

I have different ideas how can I solve this problem.

1. Just create custom `ViewPager` , edit classes from other libraries dependent on `ViewPager` with my custom implementation, just to change type of class member. So just hide all this dirty stuff from user and allow him to use methods for customs view.
2. Use reflection. At first, I thought that it is bad idea, because it is quite expensive , I thought so, but than I found the article on official Android Development blog [Android Backward Compatibility](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/backward-compatibility-for-android.html) . Here is example how you can use reflection in order backward compat. If to use reflection in this case, I can simply override method and than without calling super, change the part, but it will look really heavy and ugly. But we will have one great advantage, we can use this custom class with everywhere where is default `ViewPager` is required.

Maybe there is another good way to deal with this problem.

But I am really concerned about performance as far as this code should run on old devices, it should be as lightweight as possible.

Please suggest the best way to follow in this case, just implement library doing whatever I want with default implementation and keep it hidden from users or use reflection and save compatibility with other classes.

I will be grateful for any help and advice. 
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I tried to change default implementation of `ViewPager` and use it in library. I simply removed API check and began to write other part of library.
Very soon I stuck on first problem, than on another. So my code turns in something weird.
In case of using custom `ViewPager` class, compatibility becomes completely broken.
I have to put all desired libraries in my project to make it pseudo-compatible with other libraries which use default `ViewPager`. Just for changing arguments and fields in these classes.

All in all I returned to the reflection. It looks very ugly and pretended to be a bad practice, but I cannot find any better solution in this case(If there is please give an example).
I have done some benchmarks and measured time required for method invocation with reflection and default method.
Results are.

1. Default method first time had 0 delay (even in nano seconds). But than it took maximum `30517ns`.
2. Reflection looks very heavy.It takes from `10000000 to 50000000 ns` to invoke this method. But futhermore it prints ANR error from some(different) services  into the debug log. 
   Here is example of such message.

> 05-09 22:39:50.995      169-187/? E/ActivityManager﹕ ANR in
>   com.google.android.gms
>       Reason: Executing service com.google.android.gms/.icing.service.IndexWorkerService
>       Load: 3.06 / 3.08 / 3.0
>       CPU usage from 5830ms to 0ms ago:
>       4.1% 169/system_server: 3% user + 1% kernel / faults: 158 minor
>       0.3% 123/adbd: 0% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 15 minor
>       0.3% 2137/lib.performancecheck: 0.3% user + 0% kernel / faults: 28 minor
>       0% 245/tiwlan_wq: 0% user + 0% kernel
>       6% TOTAL: 3.7% user + 2.2% kernel
>       CPU usage from 513ms to 1124ms later.......

This happens not each time, but mostly when app is first started, so it takes much time to invoke method with reflection.

Maybe this can acceptable solution as far as this method won't be called frequently, maybe only once at activity start or not at all ?

I worry about this message, there was any real ANR (of course because it should not response larger amount of time). Is this message can cause problems in the future, should I really get rid of reflection in this case ? Maybe there alternative ways to solve this problem.

Here is code for `setPageTransformer` method with using reflection.

```
@Override
    public void setPageTransformer(boolean reverseDrawingOrder, PageTransformer transformer) {
     Log.d("VIEWPAGER","Inside overridden method Reflection");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            super.setPageTransformer(reverseDrawingOrder, transformer);
        }
        else {
            final boolean hasTransformer = transformer != null;
            Class<?> clazz =this.getClass();
            while(clazz!=null && !clazz.getSimpleName().equals("ViewPager")) {
                clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
            }
            Log.d("VIEWPAGER", clazz.getSimpleName());
            try {
                Field pageTransformerField = clazz.getDeclaredField("mPageTransformer");
                pageTransformerField.setAccessible(true);
                PageTransformer pageTransformer = (PageTransformer) pageTransformerField.get(this);
                final boolean needsPopulate = hasTransformer != (pageTransformer != null);
                pageTransformerField.set(this, transformer);
                Method drawingOrderMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabledCompat",boolean.class);
                drawingOrderMethod.setAccessible(true);
                drawingOrderMethod.invoke(this,hasTransformer);
                Field drawingOrderField = clazz.getDeclaredField("mDrawingOrder");
                drawingOrderField.setAccessible(true);

                if (hasTransformer) {
                    drawingOrderField.set(this, reverseDrawingOrder ? DRAW_ORDER_REVERSE : DRAW_ORDER_FORWARD);
                } else {
                    drawingOrderField.set(this, DRAW_ORDER_DEFAULT);
                }
                if (needsPopulate) {
                    Method populateMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("populate");
                    populateMethod.setAccessible(true);
                    populateMethod.invoke(this);
                }
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```